# How to shorten uft8 string

Tags: c++, string, c++17, byte

How to remove the smallest suffix from a utf8 string so that its size is reduced by at least a given number of bytes. Alternatively, I would like to fit a string into a buffer by discarding the smallest possible suffix. So, how to implement the following function?

```
std::string shorted_uft8_string(std::string str, size_t max_length) {
    std::string result;
    // ... do something

    assert(result.length() <= max_length);
    return result;
}
```

Basically, the problem is how to deal with variable byte characters.

Comment: The problem is that Unicode (not just UTF-8) is *complicated*. It's not difficult to snip the last codepoint from a UTF-8 string. But a visible Unicode character can be built from multiple codepoints. If that codepoint was a combining accent mark, the previous codepoint is still there and therefore still will display as a (very wrong) character. So if you want to delete a visual character, that's more complex.

Comment: Can you use boost? What is definition of `max_length`? Number of bytes? Number of Unicode characters?

Comment: I can use boost

Comment: The question hinges on what "_possible_" means, i.e what you want to allow to be removed. If I just take the first sentence of your question naively, then the answer would simply be to cut off the string after `max_length` bytes. It won't be guaranteed to be a valid UTF-8 sequence anymore, but that wasn't stated as a requirement, nor does it sound likely that remaining a valid UTF-8 sequence would be your only requirement, as explained in the first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input is a valid utf8 string, all code points are encoded as a non continuation byte followed by 0 to 3 continuation bytes.

Just cut off the string to the size, and cut right before the last non-continuation byte:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

constexpr bool is_continuation_byte(char c) {
    return (static_cast<unsigned char>(c) & 0b11000000u) == 0b10000000u;
}

std::string_view shorted_uft8_string(std::string_view str, std::size_t max_byte_size) {
    std::string_view result(str.data(), std::min(str.size(), max_byte_size+1u));
    if (result.size() > max_byte_size) {
        // This loop will run a maximum of 3 times on a valid utf8 string
        while (!result.empty() && is_continuation_byte(result.back())) {
            result.remove_suffix(1);
        }
        if (!result.empty()) {
            // result.back() is the start of a new code point
            result.remove_suffix(1);
            // result.back() is now the end of the last code point
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your approach is more reasonable +1 from me.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/xKe1ezx5n

Comment: This is true C++ solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In boost there is iterator which can help you to track utf-8 Unicode codepoint.
This way you can scan for last codepoint which is still fully inside a buffer:

```cpp
std::string_view clamp_utf8(std::string_view s, size_t maxBytes)
{
    using Iter = boost::u8_to_u32_iterator<decltype(std::begin(s))>;

    auto i = Iter{s.begin()};
    while (i.base() != s.end()) {
        auto next = i;
        ++next;
        if (std::distance(s.begin(), next.base()) > maxBytes)
        {
            break;
        }
        i = next;
    }
    return {s.begin(), static_cast<size_t>(std::distance(s.begin(), i.base()))};
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/szW4n3vqa

Comment: This removes code points, not what is usually understood as characters.